# Chrome computes padding as one less pixel than it should be

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have some elements on a page with this css:

```
padding-top: 15px;
```

It however displays wrong in Chrome, being noticeably one pixel off. Sure enough, in the computed style section of Chrome's element inspector, this element is computed as:

```
padding-top: 14px;
```

Same goes for another element on the page with this CSS:

```
padding: 4px;
```

Chrome takes that and computes this:

```
padding-bottom: 3px;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
padding-top: 3px;
```

This is important as it's the difference between a menu filling up the entire vertical space of its container and that menu having a noticeable, ugly gap at the bottom.

I'm really at a loss for why this is happening. This does not happen on Firefox, Opera, Safari, or even Internet Explorer. Just Chrome.

Comment: Do you have a live example for us to look at? I'm unable to reproduce this

Comment: http://wearethelayabouts.com/ -- It's the "featured stuff" JavaScript scroller on this page. The five links on the right should have padding-top: 15px and display with 14px, resulting in a 5px gap at the bottom. The overlay over the image that describes each link has a 2px gap on its right and bottom sides (it displays with 3px padding on all sides instead of 4px padding).

Comment: I see none of the effects listed. Try clearing you cache and then reloading the page.

Comment: then something must be wrong with my copy of chrome, but I can't imagine what would be doing this...

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the rendering of the 2x 2px solid borders your have on:

```
#carousel-content .slide
```

I am unclear on exactly what the problem is but by taking off those borders, everything looks fluid in chrome?